Constant Non-Manifold Edge issues
I am currently working on building my own shapes using flat planes - and then extruding/warping/etc afterwards. This has been a big help to my work flow but it's created an interesting set of challenges that I think are caused by a lack of fundamental understanding I have with Blender.
For whatever reason, I keep ending up with non-manifold geometry. I know this because when I: Select>Select by Type>Non-Manifold in edit mode, Several edges are highlighted. It also gives me this issue with the subdivision surface modifier where I end up with distortions in the geometry/sharp point at a singular vertex.
I end up having to go through and delete all of the geometry and rebuild it, but that just doesn't seem right to me? Again, I think there is something very fundamental about building shapes in Blender that I missing.
For the record: Normals are in line - I've merged by distance - and I have little to no 3 sided shapes or NGons.
Check out the image references for context
Non-Manifold X-Ray View
Pointy Vertex - Solid View
Non-Manifold  X-Ray View 2

It looks very far from manifold. Do you understand this concept? This is my favorite resource: Sculpteo: How to fix non-manifold geometry and there's a thread on BSE: What is non-manifold geometry? How do you produce manifold geometry? By learning modeling techniques; tutorials often focus on producing manifold geometry so that things like subdivision surface modifier or bevel or Cycles rendering work correctly.

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

It looks like there are mostly planes in your screenshots and open edges - but it's hard to decipher from the perspective and the x-ray mode. If these are planes, what makes you expect them to be manifold at all? I'm thinking similar as @MarkusvonBroady here: do you understand the concept of manifold geometry? Because if I'm not totally misinterpreting the screenshots, this is not at all manifold, not the slightest bit and it does not even seem as if it is trying to be.
